# What is the simplest way to create given for A & B type?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

I have

```scala
trait Foo:
  def foo: Int

trait Bar:
  def bar: Int

given Foo with
  def foo = 1

given Bar with
  def bar = 1
```

And I have a function `foobar`

```scala
type FooBar = Foo & Bar
def foobar(using FooBar) = ...
```

What is the simplest way to create given for `A & B` type if I already have given A and given B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, with everyone's help I think the simplest solution is

```scala
given (using f: Foo, b: Bar): Foo with Bar with 
  export f.*
  export b.*
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get `Foo & Bar` by nesting `using` clause in `given` instances but once you start to modify the values in `FooBar` the results might not be what you expect because a `FooBar` is also a `Foo` and `Bar` and things starts to get recursive:

```scala
trait FooBar extends Foo with Bar

given (using f: Foo, b: Bar): FooBar with
  def foo = f.foo + 1
  def bar = b.bar + 2

def fooBar(using fb: Foo & Bar) = (fb.foo, fb.bar)
def foo(using f: Foo) = f.foo
def bar(using b: Bar) = b.bar

@main def main() =
  println(foo) //2
  println(bar) //3
  println(fooBar) //(3, 5)
```

IMO you should avoid subtyping relationship with typeclasses and define `FooBar` without extending `Foo` and `Bar`:

```scala
trait FooBar:
  def foo: Int
  def bar: Int

given (using f: Foo, b: Bar): FooBar with
  def foo = f.foo + 1
  def bar = b.bar + 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I have no direct Scala 3 experience, but the simplest solution will boil down to something like:

```scala
given aAndB(using a: A, b: B): A & B with {
  def foo: Int = a.foo
  def bar: Int = b.bar
}
```

You're effectively gluing together an A and a B and dispatching appropriately.

It's possible that one could implement a macro which dispatches (when there are no collisions) automatically.

AFAICT, this would be the equivalent of the Scala 2:

```scala
implicit def aAndB(implicit a: A, b: B) = new A with B {
  def foo: Int = a.foo
  def bar: Int = b.bar
}
```

Comment: It looks like It isn't possible to use `given (Foo & Bar)`. There is an error `Foo & Bar is not a class type`

Comment: You may use `export` to reduce the boilerplate. And it will work until you have collisions.

Comment: @ais it seems the problem can be solved like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/e7JBFQqvRVCHG2GiqCZpZA/8